# Docusign API Sending an envelope with SMS using TemplateRole

Tags: java, docusignapi

This is regarding DocuSign Java Client library.

What are the various ways of sending an envelope with SMS using Docusign Java client? I am aware of the `setAdditionalNotifications()` method in `com.docusign.esign.model.Signer` class. In which I can assign an object of `com.docusign.esign.model.RecipientPhoneNumber`.
But as per the code examples, if we are using an existing Template to create an envelope then we must use an object of `com.docusign.esign.model.TemplateRole` instead of `Signer` object. Since my application uses templates and not hardcoded PDF as documents, I am looking for a method like `setAdditionalNotifications()` in `TemplateRole` class. But unable to find any.

What's the best approach to send an envelope with SMS using an existing template. A code snippet would also help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, without SMS, you can use TemplateRole, but that doesn't work if you need SMS notifications. In that case you would have to make multiple API calls.
First - create envelope from template. Nothing else.
Then, you use similar code to below to update the recipients.
Lastly, you send it with a third API call

```
/* example of signer and cc */
      Signer signer = new Signer();
      signer.setEmail(args.getSignerEmail());
      signer.setName(args.getSignerName());
      signer.setRecipientId("1");
      signer.setRoutingOrder("1");
      signer.setTabs(signerTabs);
    
      RecipientAdditionalNotification smsDelivery = new RecipientAdditionalNotification();
      smsDelivery.setSecondaryDeliveryMethod("SMS");
    
      RecipientPhoneNumber phoneNumber = new RecipientPhoneNumber();
      phoneNumber.setCountryCode(args.getCountryCode());
      phoneNumber.setNumber(args.getPhoneNumber());
      smsDelivery.phoneNumber(phoneNumber);
      signer.setAdditionalNotifications(Arrays.asList(smsDelivery));
          
       // Create a cc recipient to receive a copy of the documents, identified by name and email
      CarbonCopy cc = new CarbonCopy();
      cc.setEmail(args.getCcEmail());
      cc.setName(args.getCcName());
      cc.setRecipientId("2");
      cc.setRoutingOrder("2");
          
      RecipientAdditionalNotification ccSmsDelivery = new RecipientAdditionalNotification();
      ccSmsDelivery.setSecondaryDeliveryMethod("SMS");
          
      RecipientPhoneNumber ccPhoneNumber = new RecipientPhoneNumber();
      ccPhoneNumber.setCountryCode(args.getCcCountryCode());
      ccPhoneNumber.setNumber(args.getCcPhoneNumber());
      ccSmsDelivery.phoneNumber(ccPhoneNumber);
      cc.setAdditionalNotifications(Arrays.asList(ccSmsDelivery));
    
/* missing code - build recipients object and add items above */

      envelopesApi.UpdateRecipients(accountId, envelopeId, recipients);
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! I tried your solution, but getting an error on updateRecipients() API. Error details: {"errorCode":"UNSPECIFIED_ERROR","message":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

Comment: do you have SMS enabled on your developer account? can you send with SMS from the web app?

Comment: Also, which version of the Java eSign SDK are you using?

Comment: SMS is not yet enabled on my account (awaiting it be enabled from Docusign). SDK version: 3.11.0-RC2

Comment: [Update]: I was able to resolve the above error. The issue was with the cc object. Appreciate your help on this.